# Javascript timer: resume button

Tags: javascript, timer

How to add resume button to this javascript countdown timer ?

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $worked = $("#timer");

function update() {
    var myTime = $worked.html();
    var ss = myTime.split(":");
    var dt = new Date();
    dt.setHours(ss[0]);
    dt.setMinutes(ss[1]);
    dt.setSeconds(ss[2]);

    var dt2 = new Date(dt.valueOf() - 1000);
    var temp = dt2.toTimeString().split(" ");
    var ts = temp[0].split(":");

    $worked.html(ts[0]+":"+ts[1]+":"+ts[2]);
    z = setTimeout(update, 1000);          
} 
setTimeout(update, 1000); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="timer">00:00:00</div>
<input type="button" onclick="clearTimeout(z)" value="pause">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k9o6dj11/

Comment: just stop rendering the html on click but don't clearTimeout()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Clear timeout and on "resume" click set an other timeout for update your countdown:

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $worked = $("#timer");
    var countDown;
    
    function update() {
        var myTime = $worked.html();
        var ss = myTime.split(":");
        var dt = new Date();
        dt.setHours(ss[0]);
        dt.setMinutes(ss[1]);
        dt.setSeconds(ss[2]);
        
        var dt2 = new Date(dt.valueOf() - 1000);
        var temp = dt2.toTimeString().split(" ");
        var ts = temp[0].split(":");
        
        $worked.html(ts[0]+":"+ts[1]+":"+ts[2]);
        resumeCount();       
    }
    
    var resumeCount = function(){
        countDown = setTimeout(update, 1000);
    }
    
    var pauseCount = function(){
        clearTimeout(countDown);
    }
    
    $(".pause_resume").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).attr("value") == "pause"){           
            $(this).attr("value","resume");
            return pauseCount();
        }
        resumeCount();
        $(this).attr("value","pause")
    });
    
    resumeCount();
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="timer">00:00:00</div>
<input type="button" class="pause_resume" value="pause">
```

### EXAMPLE :: fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/k9o6dj11/9/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a timeout, use an interval and variables to define if it is paused. If the `pause` button has been clicked, the `update()` function will continue to execute, but will not do anything.

https://jsfiddle.net/k9o6dj11/2/

```
var paused = false;

function update() {
    if (paused) return;
    ...                  
} 

setInterval(update, 1000); 

$('.pause').on('click', function () {
    paused = true;
});

$('.resume').on('click', function () {
    paused = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call update again.
But for that, you need to put update out of the .ready closure
Prepare the function before your .ready then call it once

**JS:**

```
var $worked;
var z;

function update() {
    clearTimeout(z);
    var myTime = $worked.html();
    var ss = myTime.split(":");
    var dt = new Date();
    dt.setHours(ss[0]);
    dt.setMinutes(ss[1]);
    dt.setSeconds(ss[2]);

    var dt2 = new Date(dt.valueOf() - 1000);
    var temp = dt2.toTimeString().split(" ");
    var ts = temp[0].split(":");

    $worked.html(ts[0]+":"+ts[1]+":"+ts[2]);
    z = setTimeout(update, 1000);          
} 


$(document).ready(function () {
    $worked = $("#timer");
    update(); 
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="timer">00:00:00</div>
<input type="button" onclick="clearTimeout(z)" value="pause">
<input type="button" onclick="update()" value="resume">
```

You will notice that your code will still have a problem when you execute update() it will always do the -1s.